# How to assign XSL test result to variable

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is our XML:

```
...

    <OBJECT_CONTACT_PLZ>2222</OBJECT_CONTACT_PLZ>
    <Kategorien>
        <Kategorie>
            <Bezeichnung>AAA</Bezeichnung>
            <Ebene>1</Ebene>
            <KategorieID>13</KategorieID>
        </Kategorie>
        <Kategorie>
            <Bezeichnung>BBB</Bezeichnung>
            <Ebene>2</Ebene>
            <KategorieID>35</KategorieID>
            <Parent>13</Parent>
        </Kategorie>
        <Kategorie>
            <Bezeichnung>XXX</Bezeichnung>
            <Ebene>3</Ebene>
            <KategorieID>55</KategorieID>
            <Parent>35</Parent>
        </Kategorie>
    </Kategorien>

...
```

And here our XSL:

```
<xsl:if test="(td2:Kategorien/Kategorie[contains(Bezeichnung, 'XXX')] or td2:Kategorien/Kategorie[contains(Bezeichnung, 'YYY')] or td2:Kategorien/Kategorie[contains(Bezeichnung, 'ZZZ')]) and ((td2:OBJECT_CONTACT_PLZ='0000') or (td2:OBJECT_CONTACT_PLZ='1111') or (td2:OBJECT_CONTACT_PLZ='2222') or (td2:OBJECT_CONTACT_PLZ='3333'))">

<xsl:variable name="plz">
    <xsl:value-of select="td2:CONTACT_PLZ"></xsl:value-of> </xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="betriebsart">
    <xsl:value-of select="td2:Kategorien/Kategorie/Bezeichnung"></xsl:value-of> </xsl:variable>
```

At the moment, the variable 'betriebsart' is always filled with the first 'Kategorie', in this case 'AAA'.

How do we fill the variable 'betriebsart' with the 'Kategorie' that has been matched in the 'if' clause, in this case 'XXX'?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="td2:Kategorien/Kategorie[contains(Bezeichnung, 'XXX') or contains(Bezeichnung, 'YYY') or contains(Bezeichnung, 'ZZZ')]/Bezeichnung"/>
```